# VSCode - Cannot assign a keybinding to select command palette suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to move through command palette suggestions in the drop-down menu, without the arrow keys.

I tried every binding that is associated with the arrow keys, but none of them work.

Comment: What key do you want to use other than the arrow keys - tab perhaps?

Comment: I would like it to be ctrl+i for select previous, and ctrl+k for select next. So I can be able to scroll through the suggestions without my hands leaving home-row.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see where that key binding is listed.  Should be some "when": "commandPaletteOpen" sort of thing.  And I tried the next suggestion bindings and it didn't work.  Perhaps that command palette arrow key binding just isn't exposed for some reason?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Or that for some reason the cursor is treated differently in that 'type' of window, because the same behavior is demonstrated (no control of the cursor) in the 'find' and 'find and replace' windows. Do you know how someone could get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+i",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNext",
    "when": "!editorTextFocus"
},

{
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePrevious",
    "when": "!editorTextFocus"
}
```